# How can I create an array from an input string using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Currently I have a PHP page returning some values. The data is something like this:

```
08-30-2018, in
08-29-2018, out
08-28-2018, in
08-27-2018, in
```

How can I create a custom array in Javascript with the values above to be similar as this array below:

```
var system = [
   ['08-30-2018', 'in'],
   ['08-29-2018', 'out'],
   ['08-28-2018', 'in'],
   ['08-27-2018', 'in']
];
```

I have tried `array.push`, but it does not create an array like above.
What should I do? Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: Your `var system` has invalid syntax. Strings need to be enclosed in quotes. What exactly is your input, is it an array? Do you need `.map`?

Comment: My mistake, fixed. Thank you.

Comment: I think so @CertainPerformance

Comment: If the input is an array of strings, then you can map it with `.map(item => item.split(', '))`

Comment: The input is not a array, is just string returned by PHp. Should I put these on array of strings and execute your code?

Comment: You should clarify what your input is in your question. `split` by newlines first to turn it into an array, and then you can `.map` it.

Comment: i would suggest you to make system array an array of objects and not an array of arrays also a suitable structure for your object would be {date:'08-30-2018', in:true} for example . you can make the object with map method

Comment: If you wrote the PHP then it would be better to have it generate [JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multi-dimensional arrays in JavaScript

```js
var system = [];
var output = "08-30-2018, in\n08-29-2018, out\n08-28-2018, in\n08-27-2018, in";
var items = output.split("\n");
for(i=0; i<items.length; i++){
 var data = items[i].split(",");
 var item = [];
 item.push(data[0].trim());
 item.push(data[1].trim());
 system.push(item);
}
console.log(system);
```

Comment: Use `.trim()` to remove unnecessary spaces. Or `.split(", ")` (Note the space)

Answer (score 1):

You could also parse this kind of input using regular expressions:

```
const input = '08-30-2018, in\n08-29-2018, out\n08-28-2018, in\n08-27-2018, in';
const regex = /(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}), (in|out)/g;

let system = [];
let match;
while ((match = regex.exec(input)) !== null) {
    system.push([match[1], match[2]]);
}
```